# Restart Rx USART + DMA in STM32L1

Tags: uart, stm32, dma

I am using an STM32L1 on a Nucleo-L152RE board. I have to devices I control through serial running at rather high baudrates, so I am trying to enable DMA on the USART. With the code below I can launch one Rx DMA, but the second one, which I start from the ISR never completes:

```
void uart_receive_dma() {

    DMA_InitTypeDef  DMA_InitStructure;

    DMA_DeInit(DMA1_Channel5);
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t) &USART1->DR;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t) buffer;  
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralSRC;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = UART_PACKET_SIZE;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Normal;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_VeryHigh;
    DMA_Init(uart_rx_dma_channel[handler->uart_index], &DMA_InitStructure);

    /* RX */
    DMA_ITConfig(DMA1_Channel5, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);
    DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel5, ENABLE);
    USART_DMACmd(USART1, USART_DMAReq_Rx, ENABLE);
}

void DMA1_Channel5_IRQHandler(void){ 

    DMA_ClearITPendingBit(DMA1_IT_TC5);
    uart_receive_dma();

}

int main(void) {

    RCC_Configuration();
    GPIO_Configuration();
    NVIC_Configuration();
    USART_Configuration();
    /* First Rx, works and MA1_Channel5_IRQHandler gets called
    uart_receive_dma();
    while(1);
}
```

The first DMA transfer works well, so I guess I am not clearing something before starting the second one, but I can't figure out what it is.

Depending on some external conditions, the real code doesn't always restart the DMA transfer from DMA1_Channel5_IRQHandler but restarts it from somewhere else, that's why I can't use the DMA in circular mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start another DMA transaction you should program a transaction length. It can be programmed only when a DMA channel disabled. So in your case code might looks like this:

```
void DMA1_Channel5_IRQHandler(void) { 
    DMA_ClearITPendingBit(DMA1_IT_TC5);
    DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel5, DISABLE);
    DMA1_Channel5->CNDTR = UART_PACKET_SIZE; // <--- transaction length
    DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel5, ENABLE);
}
```

Or you can use your function uart_receive_dma(), but you should disable a DMA channel prior to calling it.

```
void DMA1_Channel5_IRQHandler(void) { 
    DMA_ClearITPendingBit(DMA1_IT_TC5);
    DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel5, DISABLE);
    uart_receive_dma();
}
```

Second variant will do same thing as first, but will take much more time.